# Learning Jquery - Building a Slider but Previous slide won't work

Tags: jquery

I am building a basic slider for practice. I got the "next" slide portion to work. However, the previous won't set the left position.

[jsfiddle.net/vinh/9ywbN](http://jsfiddle.net/vinh/9ywbN)

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong. Thank you!

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var imgWidth = $('.slidercontainer li').width(); 
var negPos = '-' + imgWidth 
var slideLi = $('li');
$('.slidercontainer li').hide(); 
$('.slidercontainer li:first').show(); 
var currentSlide = 0; 

$('.control a').click(function(){
    var direction = $(this).attr('class');
    if(direction === 'next'){

        slideLi.eq(currentSlide).animate({'left': negPos},function(){
            $(this).hide(); 
        });

        if(currentSlide >= slideLi.length - 1){
            slideLi.eq(0).css({'left':imgWidth}).show().animate({'left': 0}).eq(currentSlide).animate({'left': negPos});
            currentSlide = 0
        } else {
            slideLi.eq(currentSlide+1).css({'left':imgWidth}).show().animate({'left': 0});
            currentSlide = currentSlide+1
        }


    } else if (direction === 'prev'){

        slideLi.eq(currentSlide).animate({'left': imgWidth},function(){
            $(this).hide(); 
        });

        if(direction === 0){

        slideLi.eq(currentSlide - 1).css({'left': negPos}).show().animate({'left': 0});

        }
    }


});
```

});

Comment: Please create a fiddle.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/vinh/9ywbN/
Please help. Thank you!

Comment: I can't understand why'd someone downvote a question from a new user who apparently does not know the site conventions. This was a good question, user had made significant progress and was 60% complete and had provided his code too. Was he downvoted only because he didn't create a fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9ywbN/5/

The significant changes are only in the Javascript part:

```
var imgWidth = $('.slidercontainer li').width();
var negPos = '-' + imgWidth + 'px';
var slideLi = $('li');
$('.slidercontainer li').hide();
$('.slidercontainer li:first').show();
var currentSlide = 0;

$('.control a').click(function () {
    var direction = $(this).attr('class');
    if (direction === 'next') {
        slideLi.eq(currentSlide).animate({
            'left': negPos
        }, function () {
            $(this).hide();
        });

        if (currentSlide >= slideLi.length - 1) {
            slideLi.eq(0).css({
                'left': imgWidth
            }).show().animate({
                'left': 0
            }).eq(currentSlide).animate({
                'left': negPos
            });
            currentSlide = 0;
        } else {
            slideLi.eq(currentSlide + 1).css({
                'left': imgWidth
            }).show().animate({
                'left': 0
            });
            currentSlide = currentSlide + 1;
        }
    }

    if (direction === 'prev') {
        slideLi.eq(currentSlide).animate({
            'left': imgWidth
        }, function () {
            $(this).hide();
        });

        if (currentSlide == 0) {
            slideLi.eq(slideLi.length - 1).css({
                'left': negPos
            }).show().animate({
                'left': 0
            });
            currentSlide = slideLi.length - 1;
        } else {
            slideLi.eq(currentSlide - 1).css({
                'left': negPos
            }).show().animate({
                'left': 0
            });
            currentSlide = currentSlide - 1;
        }
    }
});
```

You were really close already. You just had to change some orders of animations.

Comment: Thank you for the help! I swear I wrote the exact same thing when testing or pretty close. Anyways, Thank you again and I will study this and see what the difference was.

Comment: Yes, you were pretty close. Look closely, there are only some subtle differences. And participate regularly on SO so that you build up enough reputation to upvote this answer ;)